# GTAG for Optimize ID

Tags: google-analytics, analytics.js, gtag.js, google-optimize

What is the `gtag.js` equivalent of the following `analytics.js` Google Optimize integration:

```
ga('set', 'expId', '$experimentId');     // The id of the experiment the user has been exposed to.
ga('set', 'expVar', '$chosenVariation'); // The index of the variation shown to the user.
```

I could not find anything documented in Google site.

Some places I looked:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/experiments

**Update - 08/23/2018 - using the response from @AnkDasCo**

Further, my Optimize experiment is configured as `SERVER_SIDE` which means I do not want Optimize to assign the experiment and variant to the site. Instead, that's something I would like to control from my end. I have injected the following in the page:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('set', {'expId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'});
gtag('set', {'expVar':'1'});  // set to variant id 1
gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-y', { 'optimize_id': 'GTM-xxxxxxx'});
```

However, the variant assignment is still being controlled by Optimize and not by the script above. In the above example I am asking it to be set to variant id `1`, but it's not happening.

Even setting the experiment/variant in a single statement as this does not work either:

```
gtag('set', {'exp': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.1'});
```

Any thought what I might be missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can still `set` values that persist across gtag calls on the page.

```
gtag('set', {'expId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'});
gtag('set',  {'expVar':'1'});
```

Comment: Thanks @AnkDasCo. I have added it but not sure if it's actually working. I tried debugging using Google Analytics Debugger but that does not report the experiment ID or the variant ID. Any suggestion on how to verify the correctness of this?

Comment: You can create a segment to check that

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: Can this please be referenced to the authoritative source

Answer (score 0):

This `analytics.js` way works:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-y', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'exp', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.1');
  ga('require', 'GTM-xxxxxx');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Note that since the experiment is set as `SERVER_SIDE`, the effect of setting the experiment and the variant needs to be handled by the server and Optimize plays no role in that. If you do server side, you do it all yourself - you can create an experiment for "page A" and then send experiment hits from "page B" and things will still work fine.

Comment: Can this please be referenced to the authoritative source